# hardhat .deployed() is not a function

Tags: solidity, hardhat

When i tried running this command, I have previously ran `npx hardhat clean`  and `npx hardhat compile`. I have the following error:

```
 npx hardhat run scripts/deployRoboPunksNFT.js --network sepolia
TypeError: roboPunksNFT.deployed is not a function
    at main (/home/stanley/Documents/full-mint-website/scripts/deployRoboPunksNFT.js:7:22)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

and other times i have a connection timeout:

```
Error: Socket connection timeout
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1099:20)
    at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1638:3)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
  code: 'ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT'
}
```

My deployRoboPunksNFT.js script

```
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const RoboPunksNFT = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("RoboPunksNFT");
  const roboPunksNFT = await RoboPunksNFT.deploy();

  await roboPunksNFT.deployed();

  console.log("RoboPunksNFT deployed to:", roboPunksNFT.address);
}

// We recommend this pattern to be able to use async/await everywhere
// and properly handle errors.
main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

My hardhat config

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");

const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.19",
  networks: {
    sepolia: {
      url: process.env.REACT_APP_SEPOLIA_URL,
      accounts: [process.env.REACT_APP_PRIVATE_KEY],
    },
  },
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_ETHERSCAN_KEY,
};
```

How do i solve this issue ?

Comment: Which version of Hardhat are you using? They made a switch recently in their list of depencies - from `ethers` v5 to `ethers` v6, and it seems like it might be relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`deployed()` and `address` is depreciated.

Make these changes:

`deployed()` to `waitForDeployment()`

AND

```
  console.log("RoboPunksNFT deployed to:", roboPunksNFT.address);
```

to

```
  console.log("RoboPunksNFT deployed to:",await roboPunksNFT.getAddress());
```

Comment: this is the correct solution; tested on `solidity ^0.8.9` and `hardhat ^2.19.2`

Answer (score 2):

I see that you are using the **@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox**. In a recent update hardhat team migrated from hardhat-waffle to **@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox**. So **deployed()** is no longer in use.

To make your code work replace **deployed()** with **waitForDeployment()**.

You can refer to this :[Migration](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/guides/migrating-from-hardhat-waffle)